# Error while starting a LXC container

Tags: ubuntu, lxd

I am facing error while attempting to start a lxc container. I am using LXD btw. The error that i face is :

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-blade1:~$ sudo lxc start test
error: Error calling 'lxd forkstart test /var/lib/lxd/containers /var/log/lxd/test/lxc.conf': err='exit status 1'
Try `lxc info --show-log test` for more info
```

I checked the logs and it has the following :

```
Log:

            lxc 20160721110431.287 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 3
            lxc 20160721110431.287 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 8
            lxc 20160721110431.290 INFO     lxc_container - lxccontainer.c:do_lxcapi_start:797 - Attempting to set proc title to [lxc monitor] /var/lib/lxd/containers test
            lxc 20160721110431.290 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 8
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_lsm - lsm/lsm.c:lsm_init:48 - LSM security driver AppArmor
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .reject_force_umount  # comment this to allow umount -f;  not recommended.
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:446 - Adding native rule for reject_force_umount action 0
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:do_resolve_add_rule:216 - Setting seccomp rule to reject force umounts

            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:449 - Adding compat rule for reject_force_umount action 0
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:do_resolve_add_rule:216 - Setting seccomp rule to reject force umounts

            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .[all].
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .kexec_load errno 1.
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:446 - Adding native rule for kexec_load action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:449 - Adding compat rule for kexec_load action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .open_by_handle_at errno 1.
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:446 - Adding native rule for open_by_handle_at action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:449 - Adding compat rule for open_by_handle_at action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .init_module errno 1.
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:446 - Adding native rule for init_module action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:449 - Adding compat rule for init_module action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .finit_module errno 1.
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:446 - Adding native rule for finit_module action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:449 - Adding compat rule for finit_module action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:342 - processing: .delete_module errno 1.
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:446 - Adding native rule for delete_module action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:449 - Adding compat rule for delete_module action 327681
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_seccomp - seccomp.c:parse_config_v2:456 - Merging in the compat seccomp ctx into the main one
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:run_script_argv:367 - Executing script '/usr/bin/lxd callhook /var/lib/lxd 1 start' for container 'test', config section 'lxc'
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 3
            lxc 20160721110431.291 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_check_inherited:251 - closed inherited fd 8
            lxc 20160721110431.293 INFO     lxc_monitor - monitor.c:lxc_monitor_sock_name:178 - using monitor sock name lxc/d78a9d7e97b4b375//var/lib/lxd/containers
            lxc 20160721110431.307 DEBUG    lxc_start - start.c:setup_signal_fd:289 - sigchild handler set
            lxc 20160721110431.308 DEBUG    lxc_console - console.c:lxc_console_peer_default:469 - no console peer
            lxc 20160721110431.308 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:lxc_init:488 - 'test' is initialized
            lxc 20160721110431.308 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
            lxc 20160721110431.308 DEBUG    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1326 - Not dropping cap_sys_boot or watching utmp
            lxc 20160721110431.308 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
            lxc 20160721110431.308 INFO     lxc_start - start.c:resolve_clone_flags:1013 - Cloning a new user namespace
            lxc 20160721110431.309 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:instantiate_veth:2595 - failed to attach 'veth4IAQLB' to the bridge 'lxdbr0': Operation not permitted
            lxc 20160721110431.354 ERROR    lxc_conf - conf.c:lxc_create_network:2872 - failed to create netdev
            lxc 20160721110431.354 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:lxc_spawn:1080 - failed to create the network
            lxc 20160721110431.354 ERROR    lxc_start - start.c:__lxc_start:1353 - failed to spawn 'test'
            lxc 20160721110431.354 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:run_script_argv:367 - Executing script '/usr/share/lxcfs/lxc.reboot.hook' for container 'test', config section 'lxc'
            lxc 20160721110431.857 INFO     lxc_conf - conf.c:run_script_argv:367 - Executing script '/usr/bin/lxd callhook /var/lib/lxd 1 stop' for container 'test', config section 'lxc'
            lxc 20160721110431.992 WARN     lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_rsp_recv:172 - command get_cgroup failed to receive response
            lxc 20160721110431.992 WARN     lxc_commands - commands.c:lxc_cmd_rsp_recv:172 - command get_cgroup failed to receive response
            lxc 20160721110431.994 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
            lxc 20160721110431.994 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
            lxc 20160721110505.512 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
            lxc 20160721110505.512 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
            lxc 20160721110505.520 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type u nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
            lxc 20160721110505.520 INFO     lxc_confile - confile.c:config_idmap:1500 - read uid map: type g nsid 0 hostid 100000 range 65536
```

Answer (score 1):

May you check your ifconfig if lxdbr0 is there?
And do you have a DNS or DHCP server installed on this system outside of the one provided by LXD?
I just had same problem because I installed dnsmasq `sudo apt-get remove dnsmasq`, and now everything is working fine after reboot. You might need to reconfigure your LXD bridge so you should run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure -p medium lxd`. If you have **Bind** installed you might want to remove it and then reconfigure LXD bridge.